# To multiply column with textbox value in vba

Tags: vba, foreach, range, excel-2007

I have textbox1 in excel sheet and list of values in column A. As textbox is user defined, I have to multiply given value with the all the values available in column A. How it can be done using command button if I am not using a form.

rng = Evaluate(rng.Address &"*TextBox1.Value")

But is giving an error #NAME? in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and it should be

Value = Textbox1.Value

rng = Evaluate("=" & rng.Address & "*" & value)

Hope it will be useful for someone

Thanks